# MySQL: Create Polygon geometry from a string of coordinates

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have extracted data from a KML file into a csv file, namely an ID and a set of polygon coordinates (poly_coords), and then uploaded into MySQL. The string of coordinates is stored in a MEDIUMTEXT datatype. I have created a third column with a GEOMETRY datatype and named it Poly.

I have tried to create a polygon in this third column using:

UPDATE `table` SET `poly` = POLYFROMTEXT(CONCAT('POLYGON((', `poly_coords`, '))'));

In PHPMyAdmin, the query appears to succeed, however it says 0 rows affected and the column remains empty. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? A sample set of coordinates from one of the rows is below:

-1.64780519214555,55.584005922942197 -1.64493672800812,55.582742082639299 -1.64452999825276,55.582998088199503 -1.64414911782942,55.582896482152698 -1.6446040249694,55.582417669337097 -1.64494635871437,55.582674741683299 -1.64471227541248,55.582234286909099 -1.64495069134859,55.582411296465601 -1.64518739534705,55.582327806329303 -1.64572123931525,55.582218128100401 -1.64516012792193,55.5827128999926 -1.64779401927094,55.5838654946118 -1.64827016444108,55.584067334584198 -1.64812256311739,55.584161771915902 -1.64780519214555,55.584005922942197

Comment: I am not really familiar with the geometry features but according to wiki, WKT (which mysql's docs says this function expects) is `POLYGON((x y, x ,y ...))` whereas you have `POLYGON((x,y x,y x,y ...))`; it looks like your spaces and commas need swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment above seems correct, replacing `poly_coords` with `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(poly_coords, ',', '#'), ' ', ','), '#', ' ')` should fix it.

*(Edit: Also assuming there are no newlines in place of spaces in `poly_coords`.)*

Comment: I'm angry with myself now for not spotting that! Thanks a lot - worked a treat.

Comment: Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.